How to use PrimeNg components in gridstack
I am using gridstack in angular project. It shows all html elements added as widgets in gridstack. But when I try to use PrimeNG component like p-rating, it is not shown in grid-stack-items. I have inspected elements. p-rating is there in grid-stack-item-contents but it has 0x0 dimensions.
I have added p-button in items as -
public items: any = [
    {
      h: 2, w:4, content: "<p-rating [(ngModel)]='ratingValue' stars='5'></p-rating>"
    }
  ];

Same thing happened with me for chartsjs. But after manual initialization, it worked.
Fo p-button, I used angular directive like
<button pButton ...> </button> 

then it worked.
Is there any way to use PrimeNG components in gridstack?
